# How to convert UIImageView to CGImageRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

```
CGImageRef inImage = (__bridge CGImageRef)(self.captureImage.image);
NSLog(@"%zu",inImage);
```

Why doesn't this work??
It said "NULL".
How can I change `image` to `CGImageRef`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `self.captureImage` is your (poorly named) `UIImageView`, then you need:

```
CGImageRef inImage = self.captureImage.image.CGImage;
```

To be more clear:

```
UIImageView *imageView = self.captureImage;
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
CGImageRef inImage = image.CGImage;
```